# Magento 2.3.1 Category Page is not loading in Magento admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, category, javascript, css

My Magento version is 2.3.1. all pages in the admin panel working correctly. but my category page is not loading shows console error.
[image]

I am already trying some solution like

> > delete pub/static folder.
> >     delete the cache folder
> >     run the content deploy command.
> >     change the `view_preprocessed` in `app/etc/di.exml`

But still, it's not working.

Comment: Are you using any third party extension, which is affect at admin category page ?

Comment: we didn't add any extension for the category page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs Because of **extjs** file is missing from `lib/web` folder. we copy the file from fresh **Magento**.now its working fine. But we don't know how its delete.